# very long run time while developing plugin for nopCommerce

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis-express, nopcommerce

I just started to change a nop commerce plugin using its source code.
Default source of nopCommerce  and its plugins plus my plugin includes 27 C# projects. So when I do few line of changes in my code and run to see the result it took about 2.5~4 minutes to show the output site.

I guess there should be some methods that I can only debug my plugin source code without need to load source codes of nopCommerce which impose such a load and causes my site run very slowly.

I mean I need only debug my plugin and I do not need that visual studio load all of nopCommerce for debug but I don't know what is the reason.

My Environment Configuration:

- Core i7-4790
- 16GB Ram
- Windows 10X64
- Visual Studio 2019 Preview
- IIS express

Besides I checked task manager and during build and run usage of resources are at acceptable level and not consumed too much.
I used visual studio tips listed [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1042975/Tips-to-Improve-Visual-Studio-Build-Performance), and also disabled some features such as IntelliTrace Events however situation did not changed too much.

**Summary:**
The main question is: *"Is it possible to debug nopCommerce plugin without need to load all source code of nopCommerce in Visual Studio and Still have access to run-time debugging feature of Visual Studio"*.

Comment: Have you checked it with last version of VS2017?

Comment: I thought about that preview version might be the reason but I did not try VS 2017 yet. Besides, somebody suggested me to try load plugin project and the debug it using `attach to process` feature for this case which can be faster but I don't know is it the best solution for me or not.

Comment: I'm even not sure about VS'19 (probably you can give a try with VS17. ), but yeah, nopCommerce has performance issue since they moved to .NET Core.